# How can I deploy Meteor app in DigitalOcean Meteor up: Error response from daemon: No such container

Tags: docker, meteor, digital-ocean, meteor-up

I have finished developing my application in meteor and I want to deploy it to the web from DigitalOcean with Meteor up.
I have read some documentation to understand the steps to follow.

http://meteortips.com/deployment-tutorial/digitalocean-part-1/

Then configure the mup.js with the data that DigitalOcean delivers. I run the mup setup command, there is no problem here, it installs Docker, Meteor, Mongo. But when I run the mup deploy command, the terminal shows me the following error message.

This container I think has to do with Docker, I really do not know. I would like someone to explain the steps I must take to solve this problem.

$ docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

**Error response from daemon: No such container: perfilesg**. As shown in the following image.

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      host: '162.243.136.97',
      username: 'root',
      pem: '~/.ssh/id_beri'
    }
  },

  app: {
    // TODO: change app name and path
    name: 'perfilesgs',
    path: '.',

    servers: {
      one: {},
    },

    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true,
    },

    env: {
      // TODO: Change to your app's url
      // If you are using ssl, it needs to start with https://
      ROOT_URL: 'http://162.243.136.97',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/meteor',
    },

    // ssl: { // (optional)
    //   // Enables let's encrypt (optional)
    //   autogenerate: {
    //     email: 'email.address@domain.com',
    //     // comma separated list of domains
    //     domains: 'website.com,www.website.com'
    //   }
    // },

    docker: {
      // change to 'kadirahq/meteord' if your app is using Meteor 1.3 or older
      image: 'abernix/meteord:base',
    },

    // Show progress bar while uploading bundle to server
    // You might need to disable it on CI servers
    enableUploadProgressBar: true,
    deployCheckWaitTime: 300
  },

  mongo: {
    version: '3.4.1',
    servers: {
      one: {}
    }
  }
};
```

[image]

Comment: `// TODO: change app name and path`?

Comment: this params (data) was set by default when mup.js file was generated with mup init.

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/zodern/meteor-up/issues/238#issuecomment-241610718

Answer (score 0):

The task "Prepare bundle" was introduced in the version 1.3.0 of Meteor Up (see [release notes](https://github.com/zodern/meteor-up/releases)):

> After the bundle is uploaded to each server, a new task is run called "Prepare bundle". It installs the Meteor npm dependencies, rebuilds native modules, and stores the result in a docker image. This has a few benefits:
>
> - The time in meteor.deployCheckWaitTime no longer needs to include the time to install npm dependencies
> - When installing dependencies fails, it does not continuously restart until meteor.deployCheckWaitTime expires, and running with --verbose shows the full logs from npm install
> - Dependencies are only installed once during each deploy. This means that mup start, mup restart, and mup reconfig are all much faster.

From the version 1.3.1 this task can be disabled by adding the option `app.docker.prepareBundle` in mup.js and setting it to `false`. I dealt with the same error a few weeks ago and with this workaround I was able to deploy my application to DigitalOcean.