# Deploy Meteor Digital Ocean Ubuntu - No such container error

Tags: docker, meteor, digital-ocean, mup

I'm struggeling with a problem by deploying my Meteor App to Digital Ocean Ubuntu 16.04. My Meteor Version is METEOR@1.5.2.2

**mup setup** work perfect. 
**mup deploy** Throws an error.
I googled this error but I cant find a solution for this

```
    Started TaskList: Pushing Meteor App
   - Pushing Meteor App Bundle to the Server
   - Pushing Meteor App Bundle to the Server: SUCCESS
   - Prepare Bundle
   x Prepare Bundle: FAILED

    -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    Error response from daemon: No such container: CoachingDB
    The command '/bin/sh -c cd  /built_app/programs/server &&     npm install --unsafe-perm' returned a non-zero code: 137
    Error response from daemon: No such container: CoachingDB
    Error: failed to start containers: CoachingDB
    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
    de-sass@4.5.2 install script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-11-29T08_58_50_441Z-debug.log
    npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
    npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
    npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No license field.
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 137
    npm ERR! meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 install: `node npm-rebuild.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 137
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 install script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-11-29T08_58_50_609Z-debug.log

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here your can see my mup.js configuration. I hope that I configured it correct

```
  module.exports = {
servers: {
    one: {
        // TODO: set host address, username, and authentication method
        host: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
        username: 'root',
        // pem: './path/to/pem'
        password: 'xxx'
        // or neither for authenticate from ssh-agent
    }
},

app: {

    name: 'CoachingDB',
    path: '../',

    servers: {
        one: {},
    },

    buildOptions: {
        serverOnly: true,
    },
    env: {
        ROOT_URL: 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/',
        MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/meteor',
    },

    // ssl: { // (optional)
    //   // Enables let's encrypt (optional)
    //   autogenerate: {
    //     email: 'email.address@domain.com',
    //     // comma separated list of domains
    //     domains: 'website.com,www.website.com'
    //   }
    // },

    docker: {
        // change to 'abernix/meteord:base' if your app is using Meteor 1.4 - 1.5
        image: 'abernix/meteord:base',
    },

    enableUploadProgressBar: true,
    deployCheckWaitTime: 180,

},

mongo: {
    version: '3.4.1',
    port: 27017,
    oplog: true,
    servers: {
        one: {}
    }
}
};
```

Does anyone know how to fix this Issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the workaround which helped me in your situation.
I described it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46615440/how-can-i-deploy-meteor-app-in-digitalocean-meteor-up-error-response-from-daemo/47146785#47146785).

Comment: Thanks. Now I solved this problem by upgrading my Droplet from 512MB to 1GB Ram.